# Purpose of mist wallet browser . Why doesnt Etheruem supports normal browser

Tags: mist, dapps, browsers

I still don't understand the need for a dedicated browser  like Mist. What are the challenges involved in using a normal browser for decentralized apps ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Metamask Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn?hl=es), so you don't need to be separated from the browser.

You can see in [Their site](https://metamask.io/) how to install it and configure it.

Comment: Thanks Junge . I do know about Metamask .My query is on the oblivious needs to make a browser